# When did God create the waters in Genesis 1:2?

Tags: genesis, creation, heaven, chronology

> Genesis 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
>
> Genesis 1:2 Now the earth was formless and void, and darkness was over the surface
> of the deep. And the Spirit of God was hovering over the surface of
> the waters.

When did God speak these waters into being?

> Colossians 1:16
> For in him all things were created: things in heaven and on earth, visible and  invisible.

> Isaiah 45:7 I form the light and create darkness.

> Psalm 33:6
> By the word of the LORD the heavens were made, their starry host by the breath of his mouth.

Like angels, these *heavenly* waters were created in Day 0, i.e., before Day 1, before time was created. The heavenly beginning begins at Day 0. Let there be heavens. Genesis 1:1 is a summary of the creation of the angelic spiritual dimension.

Light and therefore physical time as we know it was created in Day 1. The notation "Day 0" is an event marker, not a 24-hour indicator.

There are two human understandings of the beginning of God in terms of physical time:

> Revelation 22:13 I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End.

> Hebrews 7:3 Without father or mother, without genealogy, without beginning of days or end of life, resembling the Son of God, he remains a priest forever.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the fact that 'waters' - the deep - are in the heavens before they appear on earth. Genesis 1 is deeply, deeply spiritual and not - at all - a technical manual of creation.

Comment: I've found Dr. Mike Heiser and Dr. John Walton to be especially helpful for understanding the creation account(s). Heiser taught a seminar on this topic a few years ago (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nqSPFuVxP8). Walton's understanding and explanation is equally phenomenal, he specializes in this. You can buy his book "The Lost World of Genesis One" for around $12 on Amazon.

Comment: @NigelJ on what do you rest your view that Genesis 1 is *“deeply, deeply spiritual”* (which seems to imply not physical or descriptive of actual physical events)? Also where does the OP highlight that the *“‘water’ - the deep - are in the heavens before they appear on earth”?* And therefore, where in Scripture does the deep transfer to the earth (implying no longer present in the heavens)? Thank you

Comment: To me sir Nigel's exactly on the mark when he writes that it's profoundly spiritual. I base that on both my experience, and also Paul and John's application such as 2 Cor 4: Because the God who said, Out of darkness light shall shine, is the One who shined in our hearts to illuminate the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ. And Jn 1:1; 1 Jn 1:9. Also the Lord Jesus in Jn 5:39-40 and Paul in 2 Tim 3:16 concerning the function and nature of all Scripture. None of which is to say that it's not also literal, physical, accurate. Just that a "tech manual" is **not** the focus

Comment: Yes Mr Chan before Day 1. If you use the phraseology 'day 0,' then you may be making that 'day 1' because the end of 'day 0' would constitute 1 day. So i'll take 'before Day 1.' Which means it's a different creation. (Apparently separated by eons, not days.) Not a different place created, but a different, earlier--even the original--time. Which fits with other big events and personages in the Bible. (And with secular geology and fossilology apparently.) Meaning 1:1's not a summary, but's chronology. And 1:2 should or could go: **But the earth became waste and emptiness**… to make it clearer

Comment: Your edit is moving the goalpost. There can’t be a day zero. There can only be One first day of creation. Are you saying that the waters were created prior to creation? You have to show evidence for this because all the evidence points to them being created on the first day when the earth, And heavens (containing the waters) were created. Also angels were created AS the very verse you quoted indicates after the beginning, or after day 1. The only things that are not made at the beginning are the uncreated echad Elohim. This means even light and darkness were created on day 1.

Comment: @WalterSmetana you’d have to do a lot of gymnastics with words and definitions (and you’re only supporting passage is in prophet and you need two or three witnesses) if that is not the beginning then it can’t be called the beginning. It should read “when God created” but it doesn’t read that way. You’re forcing something onto the text whilst at the same time denying that it’s plain reading is sufficient, it should be spiritualized and/or not an accurate description of the events. If God wanted to say He created in seven literal days from day one without any prior creation how would He do it?

Comment: In the **beginning** God created the heavens [plural] and the earth = God creating everything out of nothing. Jn 1:3; Rv 3:14; 4:11; Rm 4:17. To me that included angels. It excluded the Son because He is I Am. Jn 1:1-2; Heb 7:3; Micah 5:2; Isa 9:6. I believe we two agree. I imagine this beginning could've been instantaneous. You and Dottard appear to disagree with me when I say that Gen 1:1 isn't part of the six days which run from 1:3--2:1. Mk 10:6; 13:9. It's not a prelude, summary, or prehash. God did it **before** Gen 1:2--2:3. Despite, or in line with, all the "Ands" that fill chs. 1-2.

Comment: @Walter Smetana Even though the word, "shamayim"  used in Genesis 1:1 has the plural ending, shamayim was used there as part of a phrase having a "dual connotation". Shamayim is only part of a "joint definite direct object" of the verb, created.  Accordingly, the KJV, WEB, and other early translations used the singular "heaven" rather than heavens. This "dual" context of "the heaven and the earth" matches perfectly the dual connotation of the "mayim"--waters--that were created on day one as part of the creation shown to be in existence on Day-One.

Comment: Well there's the kingdom of the heavens in Matthew. Nihil's Answer talked much about plural heavens. In 1:2 the "deep," singular, and the "waters," plural, are the same, so I thought "waters" plural only means there's a lot of water. For the days, there's the pattern of Elohim saying and then an evening and morning, so I don't see 1:2 (and 1:1) as being part of the first day. If the waters were one before 1:6, then why isn't 1:2 singular "water"? Why, even after 1:6's expanse, are the separated waters still, separately, called "waters," plural? I see 1:2's deep waters as judgment, not creation

Comment: 1:2 describes 2 distinct faces on day-2--one of the deep, another of the waters. the face of the deep was the spherically shaped depth limitation of the  created "the heaven and the earth" that contained the waters (Proverbs 8:24-29). That decree in verse 29 is the decree that divided only waters from waters (Gen 1:6)--on day-two, while as yet He had not made the earth, nor the fields, nor the highest part of the dust of the world ( Pro 8:26, supra). Mayim (waters) does NOT mean "plural" waters (See H4325); https://www.thefreelibrary.com/A+study+on+the+dual+form+of+mayim%2C+water.-a0293949747

Comment: i gotta see why they translated it "waters" with an "s" then

Comment: Mayim does not contain any "s"s. Every molecule of water, however, whether liquid or gas, is water. therefore, every body of water contains waters--so to speak. God is a great scientist who didn't need man's help to understand the laws and nature of matter.

Comment: There is, and has never been, a singular "mayim" @walter, only a "duality" water. The Hebrew, dual, mayim, is always used in a singular sense and represents the singular twosome, "the heaven and the earth".

Comment: yes I'll study it. 2 in 1

Comment: @BillPorter I’d like you to prove *“the face of the deep was the **spherically shaped** depth“* not using modern literature but just Biblical text or even ancient extraBiblical text. Show where sphere is written. Thank you

Comment: @WalterSmetana I think you bring out an excellent point here *“Why, even after 1:6's expanse, are the separated waters still, separately, called "waters," plural?”* Why would it continue to be used in the same way and have a difference meaning or sense? It follows that it wouldn’t. The definition must remain constant for both. Gen24:17 speaks of a small amount of water still as waters. As does Job36:27 speaking of drops

Comment: @NihilSineDeo I am Sorry I'm late getting back to your request. I had a very busy last few days and just was aware of your request earlier today. Please let me finish up a couple things and then I'll set an addendum to my answer to this question to prove by scripture that the deep was a single body of mayim contained in a single spherically shaped deep space.

Answer (score 7):

#### *”When did God speak these waters into being?”*

The answer is given in the Hebrew text

> בראשׁית ברא אלהים את השׁמים ואת הארץ

The fact is that God ברא (created) the השׁמים (heavens - plural) in (the) בראשׁית and so that’s when the waters were made when the heavens were made.

In Biblical cosmology the heavens were made of water hence המים (waters - also plural) is incorporated in the word השׁמים (heavens)

As such the waters belonged in the heavens because the heavens contained waters and the Spirit of God was over the waters or over the heavens and over the earth for that matter. These were all created בראשׁית (in beginning). And if this is not the beginning then it can’t be called the beginning.

#### In Conclusion

The waters were created in v1 in the beginning. Because they were part of the heavens which were created in v1 in the beginning at the same time that the earth was created. There was nothing preexistent for if there were (other than God who created them) that would not have been the beginning of creation or the beginning. This therefore means all things in the heavens and the earth are created after this beginning point.

#### Biblical cosmology

Biblical cosmology does not look like the gnostic Big Bang empty vast expanding vacuum space hypothesis. If this is what you have in mind then you cannot visualize what is being said in v1. The heavens contained the waters therefore the waters could not be a separate uncreated, preexisting entity on their own. Rather when the heavens were created the waters by necessity were created as the heavens contained waters.

#### Creation And Revelation (apocalypse)

> “And God said, “Let there be an expanse in the midst of the waters (think heavens) and let it separate the waters from the waters (think heavens shemayim).” And God made the expanse (sky or first heaven) and separated the waters that were under the expanse (sky, under the firmament holding the waters above in the above two heavens) from the waters that were above the expanse (the waters above the firmament). And it was so. And God called the expanse Heaven (singular and the first heaven). And there was evening and there was morning, the second day. And God said, “Let the waters under the heavens (under all the heavens plural, meaning the water on earth is underneath all the heavens) be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear.” And it was so.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭1:6-9‬

The waters above the expanse/firmament/raquia existed after the world wide flood of Noah

> “Praise him, you highest heavens, and you waters above the heavens!”
> ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭148:4‬ ‭

This implies there are waters above the heavens, and to have heavens you only need two heavens, so the waters in the third heaven are to praise God

But the waters separating the earth from the third heaven will not be reproduced in the new creation. And it will be removed earlier than we would normally imagine

> “**The sky vanished like a scroll** that is being rolled up, and every mountain and island was removed from its place.”
> ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭6:14‬ ‭

The sky separating earth dweller from those above will vanish and it will not be reproduced in the new RE-creation

> “Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and the **sea** was no more.”
> ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭21:1‬

Which sea? The sea dividing and separating the earth from the (3rd) heaven above the sea (in the (1st heaven) sky. The sea being the 2nd heaven today.

In this sense is the text to be understood from a Biblical cosmological view

> “waiting for and hastening the coming of the day of God, because of which the heavens will be set on fire and dissolved, and the heavenly bodies will melt as they burn! But according to his promise we are waiting for new heavens and a new earth in which righteousness dwells.”
> ‭‭2 Peter‬ ‭3:12-13‬ ‭

I’ve attempted to illustrate that heavens and waters are indispensable and inseparable throughout the whole Bible. These waters the OP asked about are not separate to the heavens created in v1 of Gen 1

Comment: I am upgrading this answer because of the general reasonableness of the waters not being separate to the heavens. I only disagree as to the extent of their oneness. They were not only a part of the original creation of "the heaven and the earth", they were the single entire substance of matter, all lying within a single dimension of depth--"the deep." See: Kee, Min Suc, "A study on the dual form of mayim, water.",  Jewish Bible Quarterly, at  https://www.thefreelibrary.com/A+study+on+the+dual+form+of+mayim%2C+water.-a0293949747

Comment: *“I only disagree as to the extent of their oneness”* I’m going to assume you meant that in general @BillPorter because I don’t agree they are one and the same either.

Comment: What I mean by waters being the entire substance created and named as the heaven and the earth is that if the waters were not all one and the same in substance or in their state of matter throughout the creation, then they would have necessarily already been divided by those difference(s), and there would have been no need for that infamous division of the waters on Day-Two. Additionally, They ALL must NECESSARILY have been invisible--unseen--gaseous-like waters TO BE the substance of which all the visible things hoped for--the worlds-- were made according to Heb. 11:1-3.

Comment: @BillPorter that’s assuming that which is seen are all made of the unseen waters. Lest of course the waters themselves were visible and they were made of some thing unseen and invisible, namely the Word. *“For by him ALL things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities— **all things** (including water) were created through him and for him.”
‭‭Col‬ ‭1:16‬* which aligns with the Hebrew idea of mimra, that suggests if the mimra ceased to exist for only one fraction of a second, all that exists would vanish instantly forever

Comment: That assumption is validated by scripture. Is not the earth itself now become visible by reason of the gathering together of the waters under the "hammered out thin" dividing firmament? Before, while the waters were not yet divided, that earthly portion which would become placed under that firmament, were "without form, and void"--like invisible air--unseen--just like  the rest of the waters. Gen 1:10 defines:  "... the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: ... ."  The earth was founded upon the Seas--"the gathering together of the waters" (Genesis 1:10 together with Psalm 24:1-2).

Comment: @BillPorter you’ve kind of lost me, I didn’t quite understand you at first and now I don’t know what or where you are taking this. Thank you though.

Comment: You are so very close. God used His "creating", "making", "forming", and "establishing", to reveal the power and the Godhead of our Creator. You are correct that the Word was invisible at that time. But God used the invisible waters and the things "made" and "formed" from them, to help us understand the things of Him from the creation of the world (Romans 1:19-20). The created invisible waters are a MERE type of the WORD of God--the beginning of the creation of God--from which all visible "things seen" were "made". You are always welcome, @Nihil Sine Deo, and I'll shut up.

Answer (score 2):

As far as a direct read of the text goes, the creation of the waters is not described.  It's also interesting to note that the "earth, which was formless and void" as well as the darkness (which will be separated from the light) also seem to pre-exist.

While Isaiah 45:7 (a challenging verse) says that God **creates** light and darkness.  It also says that God creates peace (shalom) and evil (ra).

> I form light and create darkness,
>   I make shalom and create evil;
>   I the Lord do all these things.

Isaiah 45:7 comes from the exilic portion of Isaiah (chapter 40-55) which is believed to have been written at about the same time as the Genesis 1 story.  It should be noted that major Jewish translators take Genesis 1:1 and translate it as "When God *began* creating" versus "in the beginning when God created."  For example, the wonderful [JPS Torah Commentary on Genesis](https://jps.org/books/jps-torah-commentary-genesis/) begins with this "When God began" translation.

All that is said to point out that Genesis 1 was likely written as subversive poetry where the deities of the Babylonians as described in their creation myth, the [Enuma Elish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En%C3%BBma_Eli%C5%A1), were replaced by names of things like "day/night" and "waters/heavens" etc in order to reject the gods of their oppressors.  The structure of Genesis 1 is very similar to that of the Babylonian story.

Genesis 1 was not written when there was a doctrine of creation [*ex nihilo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_nihilo) (from nothing).  So the translation preferred by modern Jewish scholars "when God began," supports the idea of pre-existing stuff (e.g. the deep, to your question).  The waters certainly pre-existed in the Egyptian myths (which clearly predate the Hebrew conceptions of creation).  For the ancient Egyptians, Atum-Ra bursts forth FROM the waters of the deep (they pre-existed and birthed the primary God).  There was a similar model in the Babylonian creation myth where Marduk slays Tiamat (a pre-existing companion deity) and creates the world from her corpse (heavens above and earth below), stretching it out like a tent.

As with the Isaiah 45:7 verse, we normally don't think of God as "creating evil," (because we have a doctrine of God as Good) but that's exactly what this verse says.  God creates evil.  The word in hebrew is "ra," the same word used in the "Tree of the knowledge of good and evil (ra)" in Eden in Genesis 2/3.  I think it is likely that the Hebrew authors of Genesis 1 in exile assumed that the chaos of the waters of the deep existed along with God when God began creating.  They did not have a doctrine of creation from nothing.

But of course, that interpretation has problems for omnipotent monotheism.  If there was something God didn't create, then where did it come from?  Seems to imply a limit on God's power if that stuff stands on equal footing to God.

To me, the big take-away is that there was a birth of the world from water and spirit.  This is the same motif repeated Genesis 2 (man born from water, breath/spirit, and dirt).  It's also the same motif we receive in christianity.

Edit:
Proverbs 8:22-24

> The Lord acquired me [Wisdom/Chokmah/Sophia] at the beginning of his path,
>      the first of his acts of long ago.
>     Ages ago I was set up,
>      at the first, before the beginning of the earth.
>     When there were no depths I was brought forth,
>      when there were no springs abounding with water.

Here's an additional take.  Wisdom was setup before the "depths."  This may indicate that the depths were "created," but at the same time, the language here might merely mean that the depths were assembled or "made from pre-existing stuff."

There is a fascinating take here.  This proverb is talking about "the beginning of God's path/way."  Does this then imply that God had a beginning to his existence?  What is "his path?"  Guess that is a separate conversation.

Comment: does that mean that the depths (abyss)are eternal? For if not made, they must be uncreated and thus, eternal like God. Would the abyss be part of what God is made of based on Ancient Near East concept, if that is even present in the Old Testament? We see heavenly beings made of flames of fire and wind (pneuma) which is also what God is

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown , I'm not exactly sure.  I do know there was a sense of pre-existing waters FROM WHICH the god Atum/Ra burst forth in the egyptian creation stories.  His first creations thereafter is from his spit and they are his children, water (tefnut) and wind/spirit/breath (shu).  Ra's creation was also a creation via words and begins with waters and spirit co-mingling and being separated.  And we know that Both the babylonians and the Israelites were influenced by the ancient civilization of egypt. 
 We should read doctrines such as ex nihilo out of the text, not into it.

Comment: Many ancient creation myths describe a pre-existing cosmic ocean which the deity subdues.  This is where you get sea beasts like Leviathan/Taninim/Rahab and Tiamat for the babylonians and Indra (Hindu) conquered the rain and brought it down to earth.

Comment: i am aware that Genesis account does not teach creation ex nihilo. Now based on your comment, the god Atum/Ra burst forth from the pre-existing waters shows that the god came from those waters. However, the next comment shows that there is also a preexisting cosmic ocean where sea beasts are subdued by the god. Is that the same pre-existing waters from where the god and the beasts came from?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have dates. Apparently **at** Genesis 1:1 and **Isaiah 45:18; 48:13** (by Moses and Isaiah, respectively, written near a millennium apart). When He created this planet, and all matter, ex nihilo (Rm 4:17; Jn 6:9-13--unlike in the vapid un-unique pagan stories which elevate inanimate stuff, such as folk constructed idols out of, to match... the ever-present life): **not a waste, but to be inhabited**.

Apparently **long before** Lucifer rebelled against Jehovah and became Satan, the Opponent; and was "cast down." **Luke 10:18**; Genesis 1:2a. Which was **before** Genesis 1:2b and the rest of Genesis 1. The motif repeated throughout the Old and New Testaments of God acting, allowing Satan to act, then God recovering.

For thus says Jehovah,

Who created the heavens

He is the God

Who formed the earth and made it;

He established it;

He did not create it waste,

But He formed it to be inhabited:

I am Jehovah and there is no one else...

Indeed, My hand laid the foundations of the earth,

And My right hand spread out the heavens;

When I call to them,

They stand together.

And He said to them, I was watching Satan fall like lightning out of heaven.

Comment: I think the OP askes about the creation of the waters - whether in that creation week or before!

Comment: The waters in Gen 1:6, 9-10, 20-22, 26, 28 all appear to be the same waters as 1:2. "Part" of the earth, part of the heavens and the earth in that they weren't merely on the earth, 1:6-8. They're "separated" and "gathered," but, just like the dry land itself, nowhere written of as being "spoken into being" in Genesis 1 (itself). So it's apparent to me that just as they figure into God's re-creation/restoration of the earth and heavens in 1:2b-31, so they were originally "spoken into being" with the earth and heavens, in 1:1; Isa 45:18. Thanks for the help

Comment: That is clearly true, but that is not the question above - the question asks, "when were they created" - presumably meaning before creation week or during creation week?

Comment: Thanks again. I'll emphasize that word in my Answer.

Comment: @Dottard right. What is OP? It seems to be that they were there at Day 0.

Comment: OP = original poster

Comment: If by "Day 0" you mean at an unspecified time before creation week, then I would agree.  Creation week begins in Gen 1:3 with the often repeated formula, "And God said, Let there be … "

Comment: @Downvoter, I hardly think that's fair. Mr Lott and Bach's answers are probably closer to the truth, but there certainly should be an answer from the viewpoint of the later scripture writers and theologians who did consider Genesis to describe a Creation _ex nihilo_. Possibly Mr Smetana's answer needs more details or to be rephrased for clarity, but the question needs some form of such an answer.

Comment: lol, yes, reality differs between pagan/atheists and believers. I welcome all downvotes possible. i'm guessin' Mr Chan can choose or consider, himself, if he hasn't already. Some modern myths have not only man Evolving, or happening (from water...or bubbles?); but God evolving from our mind

Comment: @Dottard the waters were in the heavens or put differently the heavens contained waters, created in the beginning that’s v1. You’re assuming heavens are empty voids of space but the Hebrew word for heaven incorporates waters into its name. Hence the waters/heavens were created in v1 at the beginning when the earth and heavens were created. Because heavens include, have, are made of waters. You’re not thinking Biblical cosmology you’re thinking Big Bang empty vast space hypothesis. But that’s not proper exegesis. Is the OP asking a trick question? The text is plain and simple in Hebrew

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - I am NOT assuming what you impute me with; quite the contrary - I assume that since creation week begins in V3 that the waters existed at some earlier time, created by God at some earlier time.  Gen 1:1 and Gen 2:1 for the outer shell of a chiastic structure.  I am NOT thinking Big Bang I assure you.  But this is not the place to debate this - ask another question.

Comment: Thank you @Dottard I ought to have phrased it in the form of a question to soften the point but I appreciate your reply. You are assuming that day one is not at the beginning? And not part of CREATION week. That creation week starts in v3 yet the Hebrew starts to connect v1 to v2 immediately by וי (and) which is connected to v3 also by an וי (and) and so on. It seems to me that v1 is inextricably connected to v2 AND (וי ) v3 and so on. Though to be fair you did say you assume that beginning and day one are extricate. Something the text doesn’t indicate and must be assumed. earth was CREATED v1

Comment: That is not actually true.  "Heaven" is created in v7 and named in v8.  Earth or land is created in v9 and named in v10 and created on day 3.  V1 is merely a summary of the entire process.  Further, "heavens" here (and in the rest of Genesis) means the place where birds fly (v20, 26, 28, 30, 2:19, 20, etc).

Comment: So a kind of backward summary. I must disagree with that part of the last comment as I find that Gen 1 is chronological, and most importantly allegorical of man's fall then salvation in life (Rm 5:10; 2 Cor 4:6; etc). If Gen 1:1 were a summary in advance, that runs into the problem (to me) of saying the heavens and earth were originally created waste and void rather than they became so (due to Satan's rebellion)

Comment: @Dottard that’s your opinion and you would have to show supporting documents where “a short summary of a process” is used in the literature of that day preferably in Scripture.

Answer (score 0):

When did God create the waters in Genesis 1:2?

Genesis 1:1-2  (NASB)

The Creation

> 1 "In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth. 2 The
>   earth was formless and void, and darkness was over the surface of the
>   deep, and the Spirit of God was moving over the surface of the waters.
>   "

This means that the heavens, that is the sun and the billions of stars, galaxies, and planets including the earth which was completely covered by waters, were created billions of years before the six creative days on earth, and the Sabbath.

From verse 1:2  the Bible says that at one time the earth’s surface was “formless and void," and its surface was completely covered by waters. This means that there were no continents. But the next words highlight what scientists say is the most important requirement for a life-sustaining planet, an abundance of water.  And that God’s spirit was "moving  over the surface of the waters."​  (Genesis 1:2)

Comment: Downvoter:  Are you a tourist to the scriptures? The answer is so obvious in verse two, that the earth was void and covered by deep waters.

Comment: If the earth was without form, and void, how could it hold liquid waters? Make no sense whatsoever. I am NOT the downvoter, but this wild theory of yours claiming that a visible earth and visible waters existed before day-three "does not hold water."

Comment: תֹ֙הוּ֙    (tohu-formless) also used for "wasteland in DT. 32:10; Job 6:18, and  וָבֹ֔הוּ (void) together with "formless" signifies a state of void of living things.  The water was there before the v2.

Comment: There was no wasteland--no ra'ah (visible) land whatsoever--no wilderness--only waters--on day-one. תֹ֙הוּ֙ (tohuw) primarily means formlessess--nothingness--empty space.  וָבֹ֔הוּ bo'huw (void) is from an unused root meaning to be empty--a vacuity. The state of void that you claim is only the "superfcial" use of bo'huw.  God's description combining the two words, to'huw and bo'huw proves His great understanding of the "matter" that He created. It was the single body of invisible, gaseous-like waters that He divided on day-two by a new hammered out thin surface for the earth and the heaven.

Answer (score 0):

This great question is **central** to ALL scripture because the answer to it reveals both the Godhead and the most intricate answers to God’s great work of creation by His WORD. In order to sort this out, you need to decipher between the four work “processes” God used during the first six days of history--created, made, formed, and established. All the wild speculation and conspiracies about eons of days of time lapses between day-one and other days of creation flop dramatically and hopelessly by the plain reading of the text of Genesis. I have written a 33 page paper entitled, “[God’s Day-One Creation – a Type of the Word of God](http://circumspectnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Gods-Day-One-Creation.pdf)”, that is entirely dedicated to those very “waters” mentioned in Genesis 1:2.  It is not a difficult paper to read, and it contains full scriptural proof of the contents of my abstract, which I will copy here: (NOTE: I am using the KJV throughout this answer)

> **Abstract**
> Scriptural analysis reveals that in the beginning of time God initially created a single bounded body of invisible gaseous waters that filled a single spherically shaped area of deep space. Light was quickly made pursuant to a newly decreed Law of Energy and the timespan named Day was established by decree. On Day-Two God made and established a dividing firmament. That firmament initially was a firm decree made to divide the original single body of invisible gaseous waters into two distinct bodies of waters—face to face—one smaller spherically shaped body in the midst of and at the same time under and adjoining the remaining body. He then immediately named that dividing law, Heaven after only one of the two resulting bodies of invisible gaseous waters. On Day-Three God formed the Earth and made the earth’s Seas from the waters under the firmament to manifest this visible earthly world. On Day-Four God made the heavenly lights, worlds, and all matter between them from the heavenly waters above. These things were each suddenly accomplished by the Word of God and were all plainly and reasonably described by that same Word of God so as to reveal both His power and His Godhead in those things that He made.
> **Keywords**
> Waters; creation; created; made; formed; established; firmament; inspection; ‘eth; ve’et; earth; seas; hope; baptism

It is important to note that the waters existed on day one. In fact, the only matter that is shown to have existed on day one was the waters. Moreover all things seen—visible—were made from those invisible waters. Check it out for yourself by the plain reading of the text.
The Jewish elders did not speculate about this matter. They UNDERSTOOD the truth by reading the plain text showing that waters was the only matter that God created on Day-One and that those waters were invisible gaseous-like in their “state” having no form whatsoever, and void, or full of void. Hebrews 11:3 does not mince words:

> Through faith we **understand** that the worlds were framed by the word of God, so that things which are seen were not made of things which do appear. **(My emphasis)**

Invisible gaseous-like waters were created on Day-One as a single dual body of matter and called "the heaven and the earth.' Visible liquid waters were later--on Day 3--“made”--not created--not formed. Nowhere in scripture will you find that the *liquid* waters were created or formed. Light, on the other hand, was not created, but rather ***formed*** as "energy." That energy was ***transformed*** from the invisible waters by the Spirit of God fluttering over the waters in accordance with God's ***established*** Law of Energy.

> Isa 45:7: I **form** the light, and **create** darkness: I make peace, and create evil: I the LORD do all these things. **(My emphasis)**

Both the visible liquid waters and the invisible gaseous-like waters were called “mayim”, a Hebrew dual—inherently two, but always used in the singular sense.  Likewise, the noun phrase   “the heaven and the earth” of verse one was a single body of matter that held a dual connotation, unlike the earth and the innumerable heavens that were made from those waters.
I will quote from page 7 of my paper to show just how those elders UNDERSTOOD about the waters.

> **The Hebrew definite direct object flag**
> The Biblical Hebrew particle ‘eth  (or ‘et), has no direct translation to English, but its function was probably derived from the Hebrew ‘owth, which means a sign, mark, or token.  ‘Eth, when placed before nouns in Biblical Hebrew, is used to flag or mark those nouns as being intended as definite direct objects of a certain verb. In Genesis 1:1 the Hebrew text shows that תאֵ (‘eth) is placed before the noun shamayim (heavens) and תוְאֵ (ve’et or, and ‘eth) is placed before the noun ‘erets (earth) to flag or mark shamayim and ‘erets as being ‘joint’ definite direct objects of the verb, bara (created). Those direct objects can be viewed in their joint definite context as that very one Creation which consists of all the matter necessary to make and form all the hoped for finished masterpieces of Genesis 2:1, each of which will always be categorized in Scripture as being either heavenly or earthly—one of the two. That One Creation’s name—the heaven and the earth—provides the token identity of its twosome: (1) the heaven and (2) the earth, from which all of the Genesis 2:1 things were later made and formed—including the physical bodies of the fifth and sixth day creations of living fish, fowl, and man.

**Accordingly**, those waters provide us with a mere type, or a mere shadow of the WORD of God, not the very WORD Himself. The **visible body** of that WORD would come later—at a point in time—this day have I begotten thee—Jesus the Christ, the Son of God, the Son of man, the eternal WORD of God.

**Per request of @NihilSineDeo An ADDENDUM to my answer show that the Genesis 1:2 Deep was (at least generally) “spherically” shaped**

As mentioned above, Gen. 1:1 sets up the entire creation as existed on Day-one.

> In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

That one creation consisted entirely of “mayim” (waters) a Hebrew “duality but ALWAYS used in a “singular” sense.”  On Day-One, there was no dry-land earth and were no liquid-water seas. Moreover, there were no (plural) “heavens” such as our sun, moon, stars, etc.—ONLY WATERS. Those waters would later be used to MAKE (NOT FORM) the numerous liquid seas, TO FORM (NOT CREATE) the dry land areas of the earth, and TO FORM (in some cases) and TO MAKE (in other cases) all the heavenly bodies we now see in the heaven, together with all the atmospheres associated with each heavenly body. Accordingly, some early, careful, and attentive transcribers of  Hebrew to English text chose to NOT use the term, “heavens” (plural) in verse 1. The Hebrew duality of the word, mayim, that is always used in a singular sense, simply does not allow a plural heavens to make sense.

If you fail to adhere to the WORD of God’s perfect word usage of the terms, “created”, “made”, “formed”, and “established”, you will never, arrive at the truth as to God’s creative acts. He both did it, and He said it the way it actually happened. Yet careless application of the word “create” in the place of God’s select usage of “formed”, or the careless application of the word “create” erroneously used instead of God’s select usage of **“made”**, will only confuse your understanding of the ONE TRUE God’s perfect description of His creative masterpieces, and how they relate to His own “power and Godhead”, as we see in Romans 1:18-20:

> For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who hold the truth in unrighteousness; Because that which may be known of God is manifest in them; for God hath shewed it unto them. For the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse: **(My emphasis)**

Such disregard for God’s express word usage of the word, “made”, yields the untenable claim that God either created or formed the seas, which, of course, were not “created” as such, and do not have any “form” whatsoever. Also, God never claimed ANYWHERE that “liquid water” seas or liquid water bodies were “created”. This is not an attempt to push modern science through scripture. Much of our so-called science only continually amounts to kicking and screaming against the perfect precepts and words of Scripture. For example, there is a huge difference between “creating” man’s spirit, and “forming” man’s physical body. Yet many casual slackers continue to say, or infer that God “created” man out of the dust of the ground. Even in the answers to this OP’s question there are many instances of rampant disregard for God’s express terms of created, made, formed, and established.

So, were the waters created on Day-One? Well, Genesis 1:1 does not explicitly say that they were. Of course, Scripture does not explicitly say that Melchizedek was created or born either. Yet Hebrews 5:1-4 demands that Melchizedek had to have been a “man” in order to be the “priest of the most high God,” as is claimed in Gen 14:18:

> And Melchizedek king of Salem brought forth bread and wine: and he was the priest of the most high God.

However, Melchizedek king of Salem was never said to be like Jesus--without sin. He was never said to have been God, or the Son of God. Moreover, Melchizedek was never shown to actually be an “eternal” high priest who offered up his own blood for the sins of the people. He serves ONLY as a type of Christ—continually abiding as priest and king, but not Christ Himself. His beginning of days and end of years was **purposely withheld** from any record of mankind for the specific purpose of setting the type of the **“order”** only of Christ’s **eternal priesthood**, as shown in Psalm 110:4:

> The LORD hath sworn, and will not repent, Thou art a priest for ever **after the order of Melchizedek.** **(My emphasis)**

Nowhere does he ever show up again to offer both gifts and sacrifices for sins. Every “type” that has been established upon its unique grounds to set that type will be shown to be **flawed** so as to preclude mistaking the type for the real thing. This was also the case with the flawed King David as a type of the real King of kings. His kingdom passed on to others. Therefore, the waters likewise were created and shall pass away, along with the entire creation of the heaven and the earth, as we see in Mat. 24:35; Mark 13:31; and Luke 16:17, but His words remain UNFLAWED:

> Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.

… together with Acts 14:15:

> And saying, Sirs, why do ye these things? We also are men of like passions with you, and preach unto you that ye should turn from these vanities unto the living God, which **made** heaven, and earth, and the sea, and all things that are therein: **(My emphasis)**

… and also Rev. 21:1:

> And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; a**nd there was no more sea.** **(My emphasis)**

Notice that the singular usage term, heaven and the singular usage term, earth, are used here in both of the above scriptures just as in Genesis 1:1-2. The sea, and all things therein **are included** with the heaven and the earth just so that no one gets confused into thinking that “waters” are eternal—that they were not created as being “without form and void” and then “made” liquid waters under the dividing firmament.

Therefore, even though mayim is a beautiful Hebrew dual word that is always used in the singular sense to typify the both the invisible WORD of God that is spirit and life, and the visible WORD of God in the flesh as the Son of God/Son of man, it is finally shown to be just that—a mere type—not the actual thing—not the Eternal Living Waters that we know as Jesus, the Christ.

**Everything that God “made” was made from the waters.**

You must trace the entire creation backward from its completion on Day-6, back to Day-One’s creation to find out that everything that God “made” was made from the Day-One-created waters, just as all things were made by the WORD. First there was one—and only one body--of waters. That is clearly described just as there is only ONE WORD of God, also clearly described. The waters were not yet divided on Day-One, exactly as the “spirit” WORD of God was not “made” flesh from the beginning. They were both “made” something new—at a later point in time—this day have I begotten thee—even as the seas were only “made” liquid at a later point in time—on Day-Three. Since there was no division of those waters yet on Day-One, THEY MUST HAVE BEEN BOTH ONE AND THE SAME STATE AND TYPE OF MAYIM THROUGHOUT THE DEEP—one body of identical waters.

Some contend that the single body of waters was a mixture of murky earthy matter and liquid water. That cannot be the case according to scripture because the waters would not have been void as God insisted that they were. Others contend that the earth existed on Day-One in a horrid state—uninhabitable and desolate—waste. That assumption is a day dream—a wild imagination--not supported by scripture. By any measure, you cannot establish proof by Scripture of a desolate earth on Day-One—two days before the earth even “made”—one day before the waters were even “divided”.

**The deep and the waters were two distinctly different entities of God’s Day-One Creation.**

That single Day-One body of waters had to take up space. That space had to be created just as the mayim filling that space was created. The word, “tehowm” is transliterated as “deep.” It was well understood that the tehowm is often associated with mayim, and Gen 1:2 is clearly that case:

> And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.

Some claim that the deep was merely “the plentiful body of liquid waters”. That idea must be rejected here in verse two because the deep and the mayim each had a distinctly different paniym (face). “The deep” is clearly used to describe the **area of space** that the waters filled. The face of the waters and the face of the deep must have been line upon line on Day-One because they properly revealed that there was no portion of the deep that did not have waters in them and that there was no part of the waters existing outside of the face of that deep filled with its waters. This description screams out that there was only ONE body of mayim having its duality of purpose contained within ONE area of deep space to be used as the very substance from which the WORD of God would later “make” all things that could be seen—heavenly things or earthly things—one of the two. This description of **the tehowm** and **the mayim**, each having its own unique face, respectively, clearly demands our attention and our acceptance of their individual identities. God not only created the waters, but He also created the space that the waters filled.

**How are we to behold these two faces? – How does Scripture describe their shape?**

Again, we have to trace backward from God’s Day-Two heaven-and-earth configuration to fully understand just how it was before He divided that ONE body of liquid waters within that ONE body of deep space into two bodies, each within its own designated space. Genesis 1:6-8 boldly and instructively declares:

> And God said, Let there be a firmament **in the midst of the waters**, and let it **divide the waters from the waters**. And God **made** the firmament, and divided the waters which were **under** the firmament from the waters which were **above** the firmament: and it was so. And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day. **(My Emphasis)**

Only the great Author of Words—the WORD of God—could possibly state so much fact using so few words with such exacting impact as this portion of Scripture. Notice first of all that unlike any of God’s other five work days in which He “made” things, **He did not inspect the raqiya`**—the firmament—that He “made” on the second day. This demands attention and answers to these two questions:

1. What is a raqiya`? and,
2. Why didn’t God inspect and approve that raqiya` like he did for other things that He “made”?

On Day-One, God **“made”** the first “Day”. He **did not create** that first day. That day was not a physical thing. It was an **edict**—a law of God. He declared that edict in order to **define** the time span called, “Day.” His law **firmly “established”** (see kuwn – H3559) **as preparation for all time** the **stable and consistent timespan** He named, “Day”. It consisted of two parts. First, the evening which consisted of darkness, followed up by a morning consisting of a period of light lasting until the next period of would darkness begin.

**The sovereign God NEVER inspects or approves His own plans, laws, or promises.**

His inspections only occurred upon the COMPLETION of something physical that was “made” of the waters, or made of things that were themselves made of the waters. For example, He did not inspect or approve of “the heaven and the earth” on Day-One—the day that He created the heaven and the earth. Why not? The individual heaven and the individual earth were **NOT completely “made”** of the waters on Day-One. In fact, the waters were not yet even divided on Day-One. On that first day, God only inspected and approved the energy, **“Light”** that He **“formed”** of the waters and **completed** on Day-One. His inspection and approval of the Earth, together with its several Seas, had to wait until Day-Three—the day when the global earth was **completed**. Similarly, the inspection and approval for the heavenly bodies and their atmospheres that were also **made** of the waters—had to wait until they were **completed** on Day-Four.

Raqiya’ (H7549) was an extended SURFACE (a new  “paniym’, or face) solidly supporting the heavenly portion of waters above the earth. Raqiya’ is from raqa` (H7554) which means, to beat, stamp, beat out, spread out, stretch—like a hammered-out-thin piece of metal such as gold leaf. It is stretched out extremely thin providing no more than a new very thin “surface” or “face” that was **firmly established** and **made** in the midst of the waters to divide the waters under that new surface from the waters above that new surface. This new face is truly remarkable in that it was established in the midst of the (then single) body of waters, but it divided the waters **“below”** the new face from the waters **“above”** the new face. **Now that is a remarkable statement.** The waters **above** the firmament were accordingly **firmly and solidly** positioned **above all** the waters that were **placed and segregated** in its midst. Everywhere in the waters below, or on the face of the waters below was under the waters above, even though they were in the midst of those waters above. **Think about that for a few moments.**

That new hammered-out-thin face was not named “Heaven” until AFTER it was place in the midst of the waters. It was initially just a new “paniym”—a new face. God called that new face, “Heaven” after only ONE of the TWO newly resulting bodies of mayim—the TWO new parts of the originally created dual purposed waters. That dividing face was not named, “Earth”, but rather Heaven, showing God’s preference of Heaven over Earth. Heaven was clearly placed **“above”** the earth—its heavenly bodies RULED over the earth, and even RULED over the day and over the night.

God uses BOTH of His divisions—the division of Day and Night mentioned earlier, and the division of Heaven and Earth—to show His preference of Day over Night, and Heaven over Earth. Both of these NAMES arise out of God’s **covenants and ordinances**, not out of His creative acts. The first on Day-One being the **“covenant”** with Day and Night and the other on Day-Two being the **“ordinances”** of Heaven and Earth, as we see in God’s promise to Israel in Jeremiah 33:25-26:

> Thus saith the LORD; If **my covenant** be not with day and night, and if I have not appointed **the ordinances** of heaven and earth; Then will I cast away the seed of Jacob, and David my servant, so that I will not take any of his seed to be rulers over the seed of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob: for I will cause their captivity to return, and have mercy on them. (My emphasis)

Accordingly, the day dreamers and imaginers who claim that on Day-Two God *created* an imagined expanse for the birds fly in or for the clouds, sun, moon, and stars travel in, are caught completely off base because God says that He “made”—completed—only the firmament, and it still stands unchanged today as the infamous **“ordinances of heaven and earth”** that provide a **new dividing face** for both the Heaven above, and the Earth below. That raqiya` was “hammered-out thin then, and it is hammered-out-thin today, enabling the territorial abutment of the Heaven and the Earth. A bird flying one-sixteenth of an inch above the ground is flying in the **“open firmament of heaven”**.

The raqiya` **was not** a physical thing requiring an inspection and approval. It was simply a law, or ordinance, that was named after only one of the two resulting bodies of waters after the single body was DIVIDED, just like the timespan, Day, was named after only one of the two resulting light conditions when God DIVIDED the light from the darkness—LINE UPON LINE, LINE UPON LINE, HERE A LITTLE AND THERE A LITTLE. No third intervening body such as an atmosphere was expressly said to have been created or made, THEREFORE: NO INSPECTION AND APPROVAL WAS REQUIRED—AND NONE WAS GIVEN.

Given the Scripturally proven fact that God, **by law, established** the new face in the midst of the original waters for the Heaven and for the Earth, together with the Scripturally proven fact that the Day-One waters had all originally been contained within the **“face of the deep”**, The question remains, **”What was the general shape of the deep at the time of Genesis 1:2 and where is the Scriptural proof of its shape?”**

The deep--the tehowm (H8415) means: deep, depths, deep places, abyss, the deep, sea. As stated earlier, the deep is often associated with water. It provides as connotation of having a **great third dimension** rather than just a flat length and width. For example, I could use a very large compass to draw a very large “circle” on a very large flat surface, but neither that circle, nor any of the surface area contained within that circle, has been, nor could be, deemed as being either “deep”, or “the depth”.

Sometimes, the deep is used as an alternate expression of a sea or other large body of water. In that case, that body of water is assumed to have a great depth, not just wide and/or long. A long wide shallow stream could not properly be called the “deep”. This would be just like a tall thin man may well be called **“slim”** as an alternate expression to his name, but if a police report were to contain the description of “a slim” being on the other side of the fence at a certain time, that would probably cause an officer to be upbraided in any policeman’s precinct. The word tehowm is always used with the dimension of deep, or depth in mind, often in relation with waters.

Just because tehowm is often used in relation with waters, does not mean that they are physical waters. Throughout scripture, waters and deep, or depth, are treated as distinctly separate things.

> (Ex. 15:8): And with the blast of thy nostrils **the waters** were gathered together, **the floods** stood upright as an heap, and **the depths** were congealed in the heart of the sea. **(My emphasis)**

> (Deu. 8:7): For the LORD thy God bringeth thee into a good land, a land of **brooks of water**, of **fountains** and **depths** that spring out of valleys and hills; **(My emphasis)**

> (Psa. 33:7): He gathereth **the waters of the sea** together as an heap: he layeth up **the depth** in storehouses.

… and, of course, even showing that they have different faces for us to behold in Gen. 1:2:

> And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the **deep**. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the **waters**.

The Gen. 1:2 deep, paniym is a plural (but always used in the singular) of an unused noun, panah, which means to turn; by implication, to face.

**The Spherically shape “face of the deep”**

Proverbs 8:22-23 reveals that The LORD possessed Wisdom **before His works of old**—before the works of creation even started:

> The LORD possessed me in the beginning of his way, before his works of old. I was set up from everlasting, from the beginning, or ever the earth was.

Verses 24-26 continue to speak about that time before His works of old pertaining to His works of making, forming and establishing the heavens and the earth with its seas, fountains, and dry land:

> **When** there were **no depths**, I was brought forth; **when** there were **no fountains abounding with water**. **Before** the mountains were settled, **before** the hills was I brought forth: **While as yet he had not made the earth, nor the fields, nor the highest part of the dust of the world**.

Wisdom then tells of **continuing** to be **“by him"**, as one brought up **"with”**  the LORD during those works of making, forming, and establishing, in verses 27-29:

> **When** he prepared the heavens, I was there: **when he set a compass upon the face of the depth**: **When** he established the clouds above: **when** he strengthened the fountains of the deep: **When** he gave to the sea his decree, that the waters should not pass his commandment: **when** he appointed the foundations of the earth: **(My emphasis)**

**NOTICE:** The first work accomplished by the LORD along with Wisdom was the preparation of the heavens by setting the outer limitation of the “depth” of the entire body of created waters—that ONE body of invisible gaseous-like waters by which “all things seen” were “made”. Verse 27 emphasizes that the LORD first dealt with the face of that very **Gen. 1:2 depth** of the created waters from which all things were made by giving them a rounded face s**etting a compass upon the face of the depth**. At this point, there still were none of the things yet “made” that are listed in verses 24-26. This was the first step in preparation of the heavens. It would establish the limits of the **outer boundaries** of God’s soon to be completed entire creation because the heavens were to become its outer extents. The compass was not used upon a flat surface, but rather upon a three dimensional area of space.

The word, set, translated from the Hebrew, chaqaq, can mean: to decree, inscribe, trace, mark out, engrave, portray or govern.  A sphere is a three dimensional shape having breadth, depth, and height, but only one face. Accordingly, the Word of God, using few select words compared to my frail attempt to explain, Tells us that he established the face of the deep as being (at least generally) spherically shaped using a compass, before he made, formed,  and established the heavens (plural) and the earth. Looking back, were not **all the worlds** also spherically shaped, whether they be solid matter, or gaseous matter? Is not **the face that turns** also spherically shaped? Does it not now make sense that the spherically shaped earth in the midst of heaven—the remainder of the deep—demand that we at least consider the WORD of God, as is clearly spoken, concerning the tool He used to set or inscribe the shape of the depth?

Comment: @ Downvoter Just what about my answer is not useful? Was it words that I have spoken, or words that God has spoken?

Comment: What do you think of the idea that before God created the physical realm, He created the angelic realm in the form of dark matter and dark energy?

Comment: As I suspected you are imputing into the text a modern gnostic cosmological interpretation. There is nothing to say it was spherical.

Comment: Wow @TonyChan, the creation of the angelic realm is beyond me. As dark matter? or as dark energy? I simply have no clue. Angels had to be created, but I'm at a loss there.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo, perhaps you could clue me in just how the LORD used that compass on the depth to make it something else. What shape do you actually think it was? Please describe both the shape and how The LORD fooled Wisdom into thinking He was using that compass as it has always normally been used.

Comment: Biblical cosmology speaks of a stationary flat plane with a local sun moon and stars. To draw a חוג is to draw a circle. Pretty straight forward on a flat terrain face. God didn’t draw something else, He drew a circle,  not a ball, but a circle. I’m curious how a circle transforms into a sphere when they had the word for ball but didn’t use ball or sphere. It’s not proper to impose a modern cosmology onto the text. The Bible is a flat earth book whether you like it or not

Comment: Well if you flat earth people are right, The LORD sure did FOOL Wisdom didn't He? That poor sap thought there was a "DEPTH". Moses got tricked into thinking there was a "DEEP" too, then, didn't he? Must have been that darned old WORD that tricked them, huh?

Answer (score -1):

This is an excellent question!

Your question though is making the assumption that the beginning of Genesis is describing creation *ex nihilo,* that is God creating a universe out of nothing. This was indeed the predominantly Judeo-christian view for the past 2,000 years. However biblical scholars started challenging this view when they compared the Genesis creation account with other ANE cosmogonies, **what they noticed is that creation *ex nihilo* simply does not appear in their narratives**. In the pagan philosophy it was accepted that water and even matter itself was eternal; what was needed to explain was the order that we see in the universe, and that was attributed to the divine intervention of the gods. **The bible, though it rejects the pagan belief of many gods, it does not reject the view that matter or the formless earth itself is eternal,** (cf. Kohelet 1:4), it just replaces the many gods with one omnipotent god that formed the formless void and chaos into order and unity. The simplest reading of the beginning verses of Genesis is that God formed the world from a pre-existing primordial formless landmass into an habitable place for humans and animals. Read for example this [author](http://contradictionsinthebible.com/genesis-1-not-a-creatio-ex-nihilo/)

> Nearly every surviving creation account from Egypt, for example,
>   presents an original preexisting state of darkness, watery chaos, and
>   a yet unformed landmass prior to creation. This is especially so in
>   the case of the Egyptian cosmogony from Hermopolis, whose primordial
>   state prior to creation is near identical to that presented in Genesis
>   1:2. Personified as preexisting gods, this particular cosmogony speaks
>   of a primeval darkness, a primordial formless earth mass or hill, and
>   the primordial surging waters, through whose separation the earth and
>   heavens were formed and named...

So to answer your question, when were the waters created, and why doesn't the bible tell us? **The answer is simply that it is assumed by the biblical author/s that the waters have always existed, an explanation is not needed or warranted.** The biblical author is just recounting how this formless *tehom* and chaotic sea that consumed the earth was tamed and formed into a habitable place for the humans and fish to live side by side in unity and harmony.

Comment: That’s a bizarre assumption about the waters. Verse one says בראשׁית ברא both the heavens and the earth. It was at that בראשׁית that both these were ברא and therefore the waters that make up the heavens (hence the reference to waters in the name heavens השׁמים ) as per the Biblical cosmology and not modern day empty space hypothesis, these waters could not have existed prior to their creation. These waters (which are above even today) were part of the heavens that God created and God created them then as v1 says, typically and correctly understood to mean, in (the) beginning. Hence not eternal

Comment: Note that the shamayim (waters above) and mayim (waters below) where made via separating the waters over which the spirit of God moved.  This separation was not the creation of something new as in the creation of light on day one.  Interesting fact:  day two does not end with a declaration of the goodness of the day’s work...  as is present on each other day.

Comment: I appreciate your comment @GusLott but you smuggled something into the chronology of the text. The Spirit was not hovering over separated waters but on the face(surface) of the waters(plural) **prior** to their separation on day TWO v6. Thus you cannot make the case that the heavens were above and the waters were below because they were one and the same at this point v2. The Spirit was above the heavens and therefore above the waters and therefore above the earth beneath the heavens made of waters. “...And the Spirit of God was hovering over the face of the waters.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭1:2‬

Comment: And if the waters were separated even from the beginning then it would follow that the Spirit was hovering over the face(s) (but it’s singular indicating that they were not separated yet) of all the separated waterS simultaneously. It is my perception that you are trying to visualize the gnostic Big Bang versión of empty infinitely expanding vacuum space hypothesis onto the Biblical cosmological view and this is not what the writer (possibly Moses) nor the audience being addressed had in view. They didn’t see today’s gnostic cosmology. They understood accurately what cosmology actually is.

Comment: @GusLott It seems like my answer is too controversial for BH, and that is why I received so many downvotes. I still think it is a true representation of Gen. 1. The bizarre thing is that your answer is following the same philosophy (namely that ex nihilo is not presumed by the authors) yet you didn't receive the same negativity as I.

Comment: Genesis 1 may not teach creation ex nihilo, but it's ludicrous to say the rest of the Bible does not.

Comment: @Nihil, there is no singular for water in Hebrew.  It is a concept which is always divisible into smaller groups.  There is no atomic water in the hebrew imagination.  Also, I did not mean to imply that the spirit was hovering over separated waters.  Shamayim and the collected waters below, Yammim were names given to pre-existing waters which had a firmament stretched between them.  God didn't create this with words, he "created" the waters above and the waters below from pre-existing waters.

Comment: We are dealing with the first chapter @GusLott. All the waters you see in chapter 1 are המים and it just so happens to be the same word that is in the word for heavens השׁמים. What relevance it there that there is no atomic water, water is at a minimum two hydrogens and one oxygen, there is no element for water? And the fact that water is always plural in Hebrew again what is the relevance? God didn’t create the waters above and below, He separated the המים . Please show me the yammim Bible reference... I actually don’t see where you were going with this

Comment: @curiousdannii and why is that ludicrous? Do you have any evidence? Actually Kohelet 1:4 suggests strongly that the earth is eternal. I don't see why ppl have such a hard time with this. An eternal earth does not ipso facto contradict the biblical image of an omnipotent God. God is in control and does with earth as he pleases, one doesn't need take the place of the other.

Comment: Genesis 1:8, the waters above are NAMED shammayim, and most major english translations make this a proper noun “Heavens.”  In Gen 1:10, God NAMES the waters below yammim, again translated proper noun “Seas.” (after Earth has been separated and named).

The story of genesis is an act of illumination (let there be light) and the separation and forming of pre-existing material.  The heavens aren’t created, they are separated from the deep and then named.  In the same way, man is not created from noting, but separated from the dirt, formed, and then breathed into.

Comment: @GusLott I wholly agree with you. If only I could convince others!

Comment: @nihil, I did not mean "atomic" as in "molecular" water as we understood it today.  I meant that they had this sense of water as being an entity that could always be divided.  There is no singular of the dual "mayim".. in fact, mayim isn't plural, it's dual.  It's like the word "water" was originally constructed to imply the duality of waters above and below.  Just like yerushalayim (Jerusalem - ends in the same "dual" extension).  Indicating the two hills or the dual concept of the Jerusalem above and the jerusalem below.  Also the word for "wings" and several others have this dual concept

Comment: Sure @GusLott that would make sense if “mayim” which you say *“it’s like the word... imply the duality of waters above and below”* was only used after the existence of a firmament. Except they are being referred to prior to the firmament v6. Meaning they were not divided as waters above and below something that comes out of Mesopotamian *Enuma Elish* . The text does not allow this. Whatever it’s dual meaning is or comes from, it is not  above and below v6 doesn’t allow it. If anything water’s two properties are life and death, or order and chaos but not above and below

Comment: The text was written down by hands living within the firmament after creation.  The language they had was derived from a world where all anyone had ever known was based there in the dual waters above and below.  The language doesn't allow for anything but a dual concept of waters... there is no word for singular waters (or plural waters). I think you've got your concept of narrative and history mixed up.  This text was retrospective, not constructed in real time with evolving language concepts.  There were no hands to write things down when the waters were being split.

Comment: You assume that the Hebrew duality is to be treated as "two". That is wrong. Yes, the Hebrew dual is inherently two, but always used in the singular sense. The word, "mayim" (waters) was always a Heb. dual and was always used in the singular sense, even as "the heaven and the earth" was always a duality in structure representing both the heavenly portion and the earthly portion of the waters--even before the division of the waters--just like the waters.